# Escape and replace quotations in VBS

Tags: vbscript, replace, escaping

I need to escape the character " by replacing it in vbs

I write

```
 str=8505usafromTo^1c0"ma
 str = replace(str,chr(34),"""")
```

But it seems like " does not escape for the string str

Please, what's wrong and someone could help me fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals need double quotes:

> str = "8505usafromTo^1c0 ma"

To escape a double quote in a string literal, use "" (double double quotes)

> str = "8505usafromTo^1c0""ma"

It makes no sense to a replace double quotes (Chr(34)) in a string with double quotes ("""").

**Update**:

If you .ReadAll()/.ReadLine() a string from a file and want to change the " in that string, use

> str = Replace(str, """", "that's what I want to see instead of each double quote")

In case you want "" (double double quotes) as replacements, you need """""" (2 delimiters and two times two double quotes).

Comment: Maybe my question is silly. I am reading a file and some strings are composed of ". Please how to escape them just after reading by a vbsscript statement?

Comment: how can we escape character  ' ?

Comment: @user3070123 - you don't need to escape ' in VBScript string literals.